# The error in SELECT * FROM events WHERE repeat IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE repeat IS NOT NULL
```

Hello! I have the error when do this select:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NOT NULL' at line 2

But It is ok if I do the same select with user_id for example:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
```

I am wondering, because name of the column is correct

Structure of my table:

```
  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.date     "shedule"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "repeat"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `REPEAT` is a reserved keyword. There are two ways to escape from it,

one is by wrapping with backticks,

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE `repeat` IS NOT NULL
```

the second is by using the alias defined on the table

```
SELECT * FROM events e WHERE e.repeat IS NOT NULL
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: There is a third way to escape it: the standard ANSI SQL way using double quotes: `"repeat"` (which is how it is done in all other DBMS)