# SELECT * FROM `Languages` WHERE `Google` IS NOT NULL; returns NULL values?

Tags: phpmyadmin, null, mariadb

In my mariadb database this query:
`` SELECT * FROM `Languages` WHERE `Google` IS NOT NULL; ``

Returns rows where column "Google" is NULL, which it shouldn´t.

As far as I can se the query should be correct:
[The error in SELECT * FROM events WHERE repeat IS NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865141/the-error-in-select-from-events-where-repeat-is-not-null)

I've set default value to be NULL for Column Google in phpMyAdmin and allowed NULL values.

Any ideas why the MariaDB might return rows that has NULL values, where I specified there shouldn´t be NULL values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is nothing in your SQL that would cause this behavior, and there is no bug in Mariadb that I've ever come across that would cause this behavior; therefore, the issue is likely in your data or your interpretation of it. If I had to make a guess I would guess that you have records where `Google` is set to an empty string `''` which is not the same as `NULL` though it may look like it, depending on what sql client you are using. It's really the only explanation for the behavior you are seeing. Can you please share sample data and desired results so we can help further.